# print a huge horizontal RadOrgChart

Tags: asp.net, charts, telerik, orgchart

I have a RadOrgChart in my ASP.NET project. It is a very large horizontal chart. I want to print it in some A3 papres, but when I press Ctrl+P in chrome browser, it just print the first page. what should I do?

Comment: try adding a @print media query with width:100% for the org chart or something similar to try to get it to scale to the viewport. The transform: scale() CSS property may help too